# How meteor blaze template deal with server-sent Events?

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, meteor-blaze

I want apply meteor with server-sent Event, like when another personal click website or login. The page of all personal should refresh how many personal login or on website. I do not want to use mongo collection as it is simply count how many visitors?

Can you write an example of how the client notice the event happens on server side?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of is using a MongoDB Collection, however, if you say that you do not want to use a mongoDB collection then the less secure way of doing it is

```
// lib folder main.js
ActiveVisitors = 0;

// server folder methods.js
Meteor.methods({
   incrementVisitor: function() {
      ActiveVisitors++;
   },
   noOfVisitors: function(){
      return ActiveVisitors;
   },
   decrementVisitor: function(){
      ActiveVisitors--;
   }
});

// client side code
//somewhere in your client code
Accounts.loginWithPassword(user, password, function(err){
   if(err) console.log(err);
   else Meteor.call("incrementVisitor");
});

// somewhere with logout code
Accounts.logout(function() {
   Meteor.call("decrementVisitor");
});
```

now use the method noOfVisitors to get the current visitors and try using the package `simple:reactive-method` to get the count realtime

Few things that you should look forward to is whenever the server restarts the count will go back to 0.

AND THIS IS NOT THE SAFEST WAY.

Best way is to use Collections anyways.

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry, what I need is not only the server side change, I need the server sent an event to other client side, I mean the other client know someone login. this method only the server know. but other client do not know your activeVisitors has already added.